# Clicking HTML button

Tags: html, vb.net, button, click

I'm trying to make a VB program which clicks a html based button but I'm stuck :/

The HTML code of the button is

`<button onclick=";return true;" class=" yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-size-default" type="submit" role="button">    <span class="yt-uix-button-content">
Posten 
    </span>
</button>`

I've already tried it with

```
 Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each element As HtmlElement In allelements
        If element.GetAttribute("class") = " yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-size-default" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

But it doesen't work
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, just nothing happends

Comment: Typically you would select a specific element by ID, then 'click.' e.g. allelements.GetElementById("submitStatus") Are you sure you have the proper control in 'element.'

Comment: The problem is that i don't have the button id, only the above information about it :/

Comment: put a msgbox before element.InvokeMember("click") to see if you are getting into the if statement..

Comment: You might want to put a breakpoint on the `If` statement to see what the class attribute value looks like; I wonder if the leading space is being trimmed.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, i don't even get the messagebox but I noticed that i have a lot of script errors which keep the browser loading all the time. Does anybody know how to bypass them?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ID's and Names:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("element").InvokeMember("click")
```

**EDIT** You don't have ID's... OK, that's not a problem. I created (in Resources, i called it "htmlpage") the basic HTML page with your button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3>Content goes here</h3>
      <button onclick="alert('Button clicked!');" class=" yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-size-default" type="submit" role="button"> <span class="yt-uix-button-content"> Posten </span> </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what do you want to do, so the button will display alert with text "Button clicked". I saved your class.

Then I created two buttons. First button will load this document:

```
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.htmlpage
```

And the second will do the work:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            Dim ElementClass As String = "yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-size-default"

            If element.OuterHtml.Contains(ElementClass) Then
                element.InvokeMember("Click")
            End If
        Next
```

It worked for me. It should work with the page from web. Sorry, English isn't my native language, maybe I  misunderstand something?

Comment: I would but i don't have the button ID or name